# Django poll showing after user logs in

Tags: django, redirect, request, signals, authentication

When user logs in I would like to check if he has already voted the poll..and if not, redirect  him to the poll form page. Tried with user_logged_in signal but it completely ignores my redirect() function.

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def check_poll(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    """Check if any active polls available and redirect user if needed"""

    try:
        # there can only be 1 active poll
        poll = Poll.objects.get(active=True) 
        if not poll.has_user_voted(request.user):
            return redirect(poll)

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
```

Maybe I'm doing this the wrong way..Maybe I should modify the request as I am not sure I should return the response here ... Is there any method without modifying the login() view?

Answer (score 5):

The `user_logged_in` signal doesn't allow you to change the response to the login, it just allows you to take ancillary actions. In order to change the response to the login (which by default is just a redirect to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`), you do need to use your own login view. Your view, however, can just wrap the built-in login view: call it, and if the response is a redirect and the user hasn't completed the poll, change the "Location" header of the redirect to the poll page before returning it.